# Possible to create a non-linear gradient?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, cagradientlayer

I've created a vertical gradient (black to white) as a mask layer for an `UIImageView`, but the linear fade is not working for me.

I want to show more of the full-alpha image and fade quicker towards the bottom, so I was thinking an **exponential curve** is what I'm looking for. I'd really like to avoid manually adding extra colors/locations, as it will look pretty choppy.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Edit: here's the difference
[image]
As you can see, there's a lot less black in the exponential one.

Comment: It would help if you show a couple images... both what you get now, and what you ***want*** to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing my own function, settling on a easeInOutCubic:

```swift
let equation: ((Double)->Double) = { x in
    //ease in out cubic
    return x < 0.5 ? 4 * x * x * x : 1 - pow(-2 * x + 2, 3) / 2
}

var colors: [CGColor] = []
var locations: [NSNumber] = []
let min: Double = 0
let max: Double = 1
let steps: Double = 30

for i in stride(from: min, through: max, by: max/steps)
{
    let alpha = 1 - equation(i)
    let location = NSNumber(value: i)

    colors.append(UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(alpha).cgColor)
    locations.append(location)
}
    
//assign colors/locations to new gradient layer
myGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
myGradientLayer.frame = bounds
myGradientLayer.colors = colors
myGradientLayer.locations = locations

//assign gradient layer as mask
layer.mask = myGradientLayer
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in way to do that with `CAGradientLayer`. Sadly! I've wanted it too.

Have you tried adding lots of stops? That's probably what you want to do. Don't think of it as manually adding stops, and don't do it by hand. Instead, think of it as writing a custom easing function for your gradient. You should be able to get things looking good.

I haven't used these, but there are at least a couple of older projects on GitHub that might provide a starting point:

https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTGradientEasing
https://github.com/janselv/smooth-gradient

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid manually inputting gradient values and locations. I looked at the libraries but one deals with `CGGradient`s not `CAGradientLayer`s, and the other is in obj-c and I couldn't be bothered to remember how to setup a bridging header lol. I ended up writing my own functions